# Filter by tags in all collections in Shopify

Tags: filter, tags, shopify, liquid

I've scoured the web and still have not found an answer to this question.

Shopify has the ability to use product tags as a filter, but it only works *after* a collection has been selected. I would like to program it so that the customer can filter all products by tag *before* a collection has been chosen.

The only "answer" I've found is [this article](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/filter-a-collection-using-product-tags), which again, only explains how to have a dropdown after a collection has been selected.

Please help!

Comment: could you make a hidden collection and add all products to it so you can pull all items and then filter by tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a collection containing all products, and then filter by tags on that collection.

[See this article](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/collections/taking-control-of-your-catalog-page) in the Shopify docs for how to create a collection containing all products:

> Add a collection with title 'All' and which you set to **Automatically select products based on conditions**.
>
> Set the product condition **'Product price is greater than 0'**. Then click save.

Then you can go ahead and [filter the collection using tags](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/filter-a-collection-using-product-tags).